# Laravel: Multidatabase migrations

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, laravel-5.5

My new project is a multi database project where the codebase is the same and every client has his/her own database.

My questions:

- If I have a new client and I create a database for him/her, how to run all of the migrations for only that database?
- If I make some changes (for example a new table) how to run it on all of the databases?

Comment: maybe this can help: [Laravel: Run migrations on another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952348/laravel-run-migrations-on-another-database)

Comment: Please review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654846/use-one-laravel-migrations-table-per-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php artisan migrate --database=**name_of_database**
```