# Laravel keeps migrating tables into wrong database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 databases so I work under 2 different migration folders. I choose path, which works fine.

```
php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/game"
```

I added a new connection next to the existing mysql connection in config/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [ ....default connection ]

'mysql_game_base' => [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),....bla bla
```

And than I added this connection as follows in my migration folder:

```
Schema::connection("mysql_game_base")->create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("name");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But the migration process keeps creating all tables into the default connection.

I also tried to add a database parameter, but still no chance:

```
php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/game" --database="mysql_game_base"
```

Comment: does this question helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952348/laravel-run-migrations-on-another-database

Comment: I was looking for the same thing so I added a new env variable and changed the mysql connection settings. This helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. When I was creating the second connection variable, I should also define a new variable in .env file.

```
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_DATABASE_GAME=my_db_game
```

Than I should have used this in database config:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_GAME', 'my_db_game'),
```

The confusion comes from defining in two different places.